# Generate RSA2 key in OpenSSH format in windows

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, ssh, rsa, openssh

I have to generate a key, RSA v2 in OpenSSH format. I am a bit confused.

I am trying to generate it using Putty key generator. There I see an option SSH2-RSA and SSH1-RSA. So is SSH2-RSA the RSA2 key or it means something else? Also is this key in the OpenSSH format?

I see that there is a conversion tab with 2 options: export OpenSSH key and export ssh.com key. So I am not sure if the keys I have generated are in OpenSSH format.

Comment: Multipost of http://superuser.com/questions/989826/generate-rsav2-key-in-openssh-format-in-windows and http://superuser.com/questions/990275/generate-rsa2-key-in-openssh-format which also have answers. Please don't do that; the goal of the SE network is to help *all* comers, not just you personally, and spreading the answers all over the place makes that harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just cited below from PuTTY manual:

> Selecting the Type of Key
>
> Before generating a key pair using PuTTYgen, you need to select which
>   type of key you need. PuTTYgen currently supports three types of key:
>
> ```
> An RSA key for use with the SSH-1 protocol.
> An RSA key for use with the SSH-2 protocol.
> A DSA key for use with the SSH-2 protocol.
> ```
>
> The SSH-1 protocol only supports RSA keys; if you will be connecting
>   using the SSH-1 protocol, you must select the first key type or your
>   key will be completely useless.
>
> The SSH-2 protocol supports more than one key type. The two types
>   supported by WinSCP are RSA and DSA.
>
> The WinSCP developers strongly recommend you use RSA. DSA has an
>   intrinsic weakness which makes it very easy to create a signature
>   which contains enough information to give away the private key! This
>   would allow an attacker to pretend to be you for any number of future
>   sessions. WinSCP’s implementation has taken very careful precautions
>   to avoid this weakness, but we cannot be 100% certain we have managed
>   it, and if you have the choice we strongly recommend using RSA keys
>   instead.
>
> If you really need to connect to an SSH server which only supports
>   DSA, then you probably have no choice but to use DSA. If you do use
>   DSA, we recommend you do not use the same key to authenticate with
>   more than one server.

Reference link: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_puttygen#generating

Comment: The SSH protocol 1 was deprecated in 2005.